# Sharing data accross the whole application using MVVM

Tags: mvvm, connection, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

This one is a theoretical question. How would you handle sharing data (data that should probably belong in ViewModel) across the entire application?

Example: In my `MainActivity` `onCreate()` I register a `NetworkCallback` on the `ConnectivityManager`. What data holder would you update on network changes? A property of a ViewModel shared by all fragments (but then there would be two ViewModel per fragment/screen(if using compose)? Public `vars` in the activity itself?

Let's make it harder and let's suppose we are using `Hilt` and we need to update some `State`s which belong to a couple of different `ViewModel`s when the connectivity changes.

What if we want to use `LiveData` / `StateFlow`?

How would you do it? Any input is appreciated!

EDIT:

This is the structure I'm talking about.

```
MainActivity
    val mainViewModel by viewModels()
    onCreate()
        ConnectivityManager.registerDefaultCallback() // The callback updates values inside mainViewModel
        setContent {} // Here we enter compose world.
            NavHost()
                BottomSheet(viewModel: BottomSheetViewModel = viewModel())
                    // Inside here I query viewModel.state to get the state of a web request. 
                    // This state should take into account the connection state and if none is available it should be State.NO_CONNECTION
```

Comment: Are you using Navigation Components?

Comment: If you are it's easy to register the changes in the activity and from there update the view as opposed to using it individually in each fragment.

Comment: Yes I am using Navigation Components. But the State that needs to be updated when the connection changes is updated from a ViewModel which takes into account other factors.

Comment: Ideally I would want every viewModel to have that information (among the others), like if any viewModel were to extend a singleton.

Comment: Florian explains the dataStore here. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dd_Lv7AxqkY&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuCfAe7QK2BoMPkv2TGM_b0E&index=7
DataStore returns a flow which can be converted into liveData.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you save your network state (plus other stuff) in a dataStore class which will then return a flow that you can convert into LiveData.

From there you can subscribe to the Flow (in your ViewModel) and convert it into Livedata, which can then be observed from each Fragment.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dd_Lv7AxqkY&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuCfAe7QK2BoMPkv2TGM_b0E&index=7

Watch this video for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Okay, this is very cool and good to know but... I have updated the question with a better description of the structure my app has. To get the network value inside the viewModel in order to then combine the two things I would need to either hoist the viewModel up the tree (which is not right imo) or pass down the tree a Flow/LiveData which may be better then the other option but it's still a bit rough I think... How would you sort this?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your situation, however I used a network listener as a LiveData class, which I can listen to from all viewmodels.
https://github.com/E5c11/TicTacToe_3D/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/esc/test/apps/network/ConnectionLiveData.java

Comment: It listens for network changes, if the network comes online, it sends a request to check if the network actually has a connection.

Comment: Yeah but you are initializing a callback every time you create a viewModel, aren't you? The delay caused by that is probably absolutely not notable but what I was wondering is if there is a way I didn't think of of creating a  callback just once in the activity and then propagating the livedata/flow/whatever to the other viewmodels!

Comment: No, I creat a provides method in AppModule(Dagger Hilt)
https://github.com/E5c11/TicTacToe_3D/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/esc/test/apps/dagger/AppModule.java

Comment: Then you just get a reference to the instance with constructor injection.
Works perfectly in my app. Unfortunately still in Java since it's an old app.
Take a look at my loginviewmodel where I got a reference to the LiveData object

Comment: Oh okay, this makes much more sense now! I'm going to try to implement something like that in Kotlin!

Answer (score 0):

To get network updates(not only connection but network validity) in the form of LiveData.

You can add this class

https://github.com/E5c11/TicTacToe_3D/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/esc/test/apps/network/ConnectionLiveData.java

It returns a boolean value which can be observed as LiveData in all classes/fragments when added as a Singleton (in Dagger).

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideNetworkReport(Application app) = ConnectionLiveData(app)
```

You are then able to call it or inject it in the ViewModel with

```
val network: ConnectionLiveData
```

Then return it to the Fragment with

```
fun getNetwork() = network
```